# Passing varargs to Spring spEL causes "Method cannot be found on com.sun.proxy"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

I try to write custom class for permissions evaluation, so it can be used with Spring Security `@PreAuthorize` and Spring Expression Language like for example this (`authority` is just a regular Spring component with some role names):

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionEvaluator.anyOfRoles(@authority.ADMIN)")
```

The `PermissionEvaluator#anyOfRoles` method declaration looks like follows:

```
boolean anyOfRoles(String... roles)
```

As shown this method takes varargs of String type. It works fine when only one parameter is passed (as on the example above) but calling it with more than one argument, eg.

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionEvaluator.anyOfRoles(@authority.ADMIN, @authority.USER)")
```

causes

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method anyOfRoles(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132 type
```

to be thrown. It still works when called with an array of Strings (basically same as varargs, which is just syntactic sugar), like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionEvaluator.anyOfRoles(new String[] { @authority.ADMIN, @authority.USER })")
```

I tried to look some additional info about passing varargs with spEL but Spring documentation only enigmatically [mentions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-methods) in spEL documentation that

> Varargs are also supported.

What might be the cause of this exception and is there other workaround than passing array in spEL?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spring are you using? I just ran this test case with 4.3.12 and it worked fine...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46953884Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46953884Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("#{foo.foo('a', 'b')}")
    private String foo;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> System.out.println(foo);
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        public String foo(String... strings) {
            return "filled: " + Arrays.toString(strings);
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

```
filled: [a, b]
```

Comment: I'm running Spring 4.3.12 (as it is the version shipped with Spring Boot 1.5.8 which I'm using). Just to ensure that it is not a problem with retrieveing variables values (I'm getting them from another component) I tried to pass those strings in spEL as literals but got the same exception.

Comment: Interesting; I can reproduce with the security stuff ... investigating ...

Comment: It's a problem when the bean in question is a proxy; I opened this [SPR-16122](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16122) JIRA issue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for investigating and taking action on this, I will stick to using arrays as my varargs for now and follow the issue to be updated.

Comment: Juergen has already fixed the JIRA, it will be in the next release (and boot 1.5.9, I presume).