# IllegalArgumentException on expression language with varargs parameter can not be translated to Ljava.lang.String

Tags: java, el

Is there a way to call a varargs method in EL?

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Cannot convert aa of type class java.lang.String to class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

**index.xhtml**

```
...
#{applicationBean.usuari.isInRoles('aa','bb')}
...
```

**Code in Bean**

```
...
public boolean isInRoles(String...roles) {
    return activeRols.containsAll(Arrays.asList(roles));
}
...
```

Comment: Hmm, what is your Spring version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953884/passing-varargs-to-spring-spel-causes-method-cannot-be-found-on-com-sun-proxy seems to have a similar problem - according to the documentation, varargs are supported in EL: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-methods

Comment: I don't use Spring

Comment: Okay, sorry, seems I was on the wrong track here.